# Gaussian Expectation, using maximum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, gaussian-measure

Let $(A,B)$ have a standard Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find, $\mathbb{E}[max(2.5A+B, A + 2.5Y)]$

I thought that this could first be rewritten as $\mathbb{E}(2.5A+B|A>B)*\mathbb{P}(A>B) + \mathbb{E}(A+2.5B|A<B)*\mathbb{P}(A<B)$.

However, this has not made the calculation any easier.

Comment: (see edit) - more like this?

Comment: yeah, thats correct (thought probably not helpful, as you noted)

Comment: Since $(X,Y)=(cA+B, A + cB)$ is bivariate normal with $EX=EY=0$, [it can be shown](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/139090/8030) that $Z=\max(X,Y)$ has a [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) with PDF $f(z)=2\phi(z)\Phi(\alpha z)$ where $\alpha={1-\rho\over\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$ 
 and $\rho=\text{corr}(X,Y)$ ($={2c\over c^2+1}$ if I did the calculation right). According to that second link, it then turns out that $EZ=\sqrt{1-\rho\over\pi}$ (although deriving this by direct integration might be non-trivial).

Comment: Thanks, but how would $ρ=corr(X,Y)$ be calculated to give the final answer, when the question doesn't give the figures of X and Y?

Comment: $(X,Y)$ is given in terms of your $(A,B)$ and $c=2.5$. Then $\rho:={E(XY)-EX\cdot EY\over \sqrt{V(X)\cdot V(Y)}}={2c\over c^2+1}.$

Comment: Oh, thank you! So I would get $ρ = \frac{2(2.5)}{(2.5^2+1} = \frac{20}{29}, \ then \ \mathbb{E}(Z) = \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{20}{29}}{\pi}}  \approx 0.3143 $

Answer (score 1):

Here is an actual simplification:

- If $(A,B)$ are independent Gaussians (with variance $1$), then $(X=A+B,Y=A-B)$ are also independent Gaussians (with variance $2$).
- So you can rewrite
  \begin{align}
  \max(2.5A+B, A+2.5B)&=\max(1.75X+0.75Y,1.75X-0.75Y) \\
  &=0.75X + \max(0.75Y,-0.75Y) \\
  &=0.75X + 0.75|Y| \\
  \end{align}
- Now the expectation value of $X$ is zero. And $|Y|$ has a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution), which has expecation value $\frac{\sigma\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ in general, and here we have $\sigma^2=2$. Therefore the complete answer is
  \begin{align}
  0.75\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
  \end{align}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so next step is to split up into $\mathbb{E}(0.75X) + \mathbb{E}(max(0.75Y,-0.75Y)$. Then just find how to calculate the expectations

Comment: I am still confused as to how to calculate the expectations

Comment: I added some more. hope it helps.